# Python: How to use regex to find a repetitive string

Tags: regex, python-3.x, recursion, data-extraction

I have some data that I want to extract/ output when a keyword is found in the block of data. How can I retrieve all the data from the first '#' to the last ')' using regular expression?

```
//Log_1.txt
# DON'T WANT #
{12345.54321}
[Tues Jul 2 01:23:45 2019]
< SOME_TYPE 
(some_ID = [12345] reportChange::someMoreInfo called with invalid some ID)

# DON'T WANT #
{12345.54321}
[Tues Jul 2 01:23:45 2019]
< SOME_TYPE 
(some_ID = [12345] failed::someMoreInfo called with invalid some ID)
```

CODE

```
import re

with open("Log_1.txt", 'r') as f:
    result = re.search('#(.*)#', f.read())

print(result.group(0))
```

This isn't all of my code but if the keyword is "reportChange", the output should be >>>

```
# DON'T WANT #
  .
  .
  .
(some_ID = [12345] reportChange::someMoreInfo called with invalid some ID)
```

instead of

```
# DON'T WANT #
```

Comment: so you want `DON'T WANT`  .... seems like a bad comment

Comment: Yes, I want it right now but eventually plan to not have that. @depperm

Comment: if the keyword is `someMoreInfo` do you want the whole log or just from the nearest comment `DON'T WANT`

Comment: Yes I want the entire block of data the keyword is in and separated by the empty new line @depperm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want from the latest `# DON'T WANT #` you can use the regex `#(.*)#[^)]+yourKeyWordHere[^)]+\)`. In python you can use string formatting and have `{}` in place of the keyword to replace with whatever word you want.

```
import re

keyword='reportChange'

with open("Log_1.txt", 'r') as f:
    result = re.search('#(.*)#[^)]+{}[^)]+\)'.format(keyword), f.read())

print(result.group(0))
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution worked, but I need it to output the block of data each time the keyword is found. Not just the first instance or the last instance.

Answer (score 1):

As regular expression you have to use a negative lookahead, as well as a negative lookbehind.

Try this: `(?!#).*(?<![)])` as regex. It should output everything between # and ).

For the future: Use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to test your regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This code prints only blocks of data where there's `reportChange::someMoreInfo called with invalid some ID`:

```
data = '''//Log_1.txt
# DON'T WANT #
{12345.54321}
[Tues Jul 2 01:23:45 2019]
< SOME_TYPE
(some_ID = [12345] reportChange::someMoreInfo called with invalid some ID)

# DON'T WANT #
{12345.54321}
[Tues Jul 2 01:23:45 2019]
< SOME_TYPE
(some_ID = [12345] failed::someMoreInfo called with invalid some ID)

# DON'T WANT #
{12345.54321}
[Tues Jul 2 01:23:45 2019]
< SOME_TYPE
(some_ID = [12345xxx] reportChange::someMoreInfo called with invalid some ID)
'''

import re

for d in re.split(r'\n\n', data):
    g = re.findall(r'^# DON\'T WANT #.*reportChange::someMoreInfo called with invalid some ID\)$', d, flags=re.M|re.DOTALL)
    if g:
        print(g[0])
        print()
```

Prints:

```
# DON'T WANT #
{12345.54321}
[Tues Jul 2 01:23:45 2019]
< SOME_TYPE
(some_ID = [12345] reportChange::someMoreInfo called with invalid some ID)

# DON'T WANT #
{12345.54321}
[Tues Jul 2 01:23:45 2019]
< SOME_TYPE
(some_ID = [12345xxx] reportChange::someMoreInfo called with invalid some ID)
```